# How to create a ternary relationship that has a weak entity?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, relational-database, data-modeling

I am developing a system where there are `doctor` , `patient` and `diagnosis`.
I made `diagnosis` a weak entity because without a doctor or a patient there will not be a diagnosis.

now I want to make a relationship called `treatment` between `doctor` and `patient` and `diagnosis` where a specific doctor will treat a specific patient that has a specific diagnosis.

how to make the relationship given that `diagnosis` is a weak entity that will not have it's own primary key.

Comment: Why do you say `diagnosis` won't have a primary key?

Comment: @TabAlleman because it is a weak entity so the primary key will be of another entity that it depends on

Comment: That has nothing to do with a primary key though. We assume doctor, patient, and diagnosis are all in different tables based on your question. I think you are confusing primary and foreign keys here. The Visit table can have a visitid, doctor, patient, and diagnosis. The visitid is a primary key, and the other columns are foreign keys which reference the patient, doctor, and diagnosis tables (or whatever you want).

Comment: termary relationships takes the primary keys of all the 3 entities that participate in the relationship. now one of the entities is weak which means it will have the same keys of other entities that participate how to handle that in the treatment table ..

Comment: @scsimon yes every one is in his own table

Comment: Post your DDL for the (at least 4 tables) related to this question. That will help.

Comment: @scsimon i work on papers :D

Comment: @scsimon the point is the treatment table will have the three primary keys of the doctor , patient and diagnosis . and diagnosis already have its primary keys of patient and doctors because it depends on them so there will be duplicates in treatment table ?

Comment: Is it possible for the same doctor to give more than one diagnosis for the same patient?   In other words, isn't there any combination of columns in `diagnosis` that will be unique for each row?   Or will it be possible to have exact duplicate rows in that table?   I think maybe you're not aware that a Primary Key doesn't have to be only one column.   There is no reason a weak entity can't have a primary key.  In fact it usually does:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_entity

Comment: @ahmednader Please edit your Q and add the DDL for the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your fundamental understanding of weak entities and primary keys is flawed.

You seem to think that because the weak entity table "includes" the primary keys of two other tables, that means it can't have a primary key of its own.

This is not the case.   A Primary Key can be the combination of multiple columns, as long as that combination is Unique for all rows.

Based on what you describe you should have something like this:

```
Table Doctor
Primary Key:  DoctorID

Table Patient
Primary Key:  PatientID

Table Diagnosis
Primary Key:  DoctorID, PatientID (or an Identity column to form an artificial PK)
Foreign Key:  DoctorID References Table Doctor
Foreign Key:  PatientID References Table Patient

So finally, 

Table Treatment
Primary Key:  DoctorID, PatientID (, Identity column of Table Diagnosis if you created one)
Foreign Key:  DoctorID References Table Doctor
Foreign Key:  PatientID References Table Patient
```

This is sufficient if a doctor can only diagnose each patient once, and also can only suggest one treatment per patient.   If either of these combinations can have more than one instance, then you should add some third "Line Number" type column to the PK of the Diagnosis and/or Treatment table to include in the PK for that table and make it unique.

Comment: great , but what i mean is the treatment will have the id of doctor from doctor table and id of patient from patient table , so i dont need  the same ids from diagnosis table , you understand what i mean  ?

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying and you are absolutely wrong.  The ids from the patient & doctor table uniquely identify a diagnosis, and therefore they also uniquely identify a treatment.  OR, as I stated, you can add an IDENTITY column to the Diagnosis table, and reference that in the Diagnosis table instead of the Doctor/Patient IDs.

Comment: ah okay i understand now , thanks for your answer . it helped

Comment: so now the diagnosis is a relationship between doctor and patient . and the diagnosis relationship is participating as an entity in the treatment relationship . am i right ?

Comment: Yes, I believe you have it.